# Moving or inserting data to other SQL table with format

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Im trying to move my data from one table to another is sql serve r.

problem is new table have new structure other than my old one.

this is my old table :

```
Column 0    Column 1    Column 2    Column 3    Column 4    Column 5
12312323      07:31      15:30                               6390
12312342      07:31      15:21                               6390
12334323      07:21      09:20       12:30      15:04        93444
12323323      07:28      10:05       11:28      15:09        93444
23512323      07:26      08:21       14:04      14:34        93444
12452323      07:16      10:44       11:53      15:08        93444
```

"Column 0" is a User id , and other column is user hour/Clock interaction with system.

now i want to get this output in another table :

```
Column 0    Column 1    Column 2    Column 3
12312323      07:31      15:30      6390                                                            
12312342      07:31      15:21      6390                                                            
12334323      07:21      09:20      93444
12334323      12:30      15:04      93444                                               
12323323      07:28      10:05      93444
12323323      11:28      15:09      93444
23512323      07:26      08:21      93444                                                                   
23512323      14:04      14:34      93444
12452323      07:16      10:44      93444
12452323      11:53      15:08      93444
```

as u can see in second table , im removing  every row from table one that have  value in "Column3,Column4"  and adding them in next row into new table

Comment: Srry i Couldnt add SqlServe r tag or even using Serve r word, firewall bans me to use that word and avoid question to be poster. Im using Sql Serve r 2008r.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with `union all`:

```
select col0, col1, col2, col5
from oldtable
union all
select col0, col1, col3, col4
from oldtable
where col3 is not null;
```

If you want to put this into a new table, use either `insert` or `select into`.  For instance:

```
select col0, col1, col3, col4
into newtable
from (select col0, col1, col2 as col3, col5 as col4
      from oldtable
      union all
      select col0, col1, col3, col4
      from oldtable
      where col3 is not null
     ) t
```

Comment: THanks Alot , with a little modificaiton that do the trick :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you could use UNION ALL to achieve required result:

```
INSERT INTO new_table
SELECT   [Column 0], [Column 1], [Column 2], [Column 5]
FROM     old_table
UNION ALL
SELECT   [Column 0], [Column 3], [Column 4], [Column 5]
FROM     old_table
WHERE    [Column 3] IS NOT NULL AND [Column 4] IS NOT NULL
```